# Ruby unexpected $end, expecting kEND

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting the following error:

> unexpected $end, expecting kEND

Does `rescue` require `end`? How about `begin`? Am I missing an `end` somewhere?

```
class AdAssistedController < CommonController
  def initialize
    super
    @pageJs = ['ad_assisted']
    @pageCSS = ['ad_creator', 'fbx_launcher', 'score_dashboard', 
                'slider_dashboard_new', 'score-dashboard_new',
                'jquery-ui']
  end

  def index
    begin
      @feed_names = FbxLauncher::Feed.find(:all)
    rescue Exception => e
      log_error(e.message)
      log_error(e.backtrace)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :partial => 'index'}
      format.html { render :partial => 'index'}
    end
  end
```

Comment: You need an `end`  to match the `class`. The block starting `begin` needs a single `end`, a more complete (though not exhaustive) syntax precis might be `begin...rescue...ensure...end`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an end for your class.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use consistent tags/spaces when you write your code. And there is one "end" missing in the end of your file (that kEND) means.

```
class AdAssistedController < CommonController

  def initialize
    super
    @pageJs = ['ad_assisted']
    @pageCSS = ['ad_creator', 'fbx_launcher', 'score_dashboard', 
                'slider_dashboard_new', 'score-dashboard_new',
                'jquery-ui']
  end

  def index
    begin
      @feed_names = FbxLauncher::Feed.find(:all)

    rescue Exception => e
      log_error(e.message)
      log_error(e.backtrace)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :partial => 'index'}
      format.html { render :partial => 'index'}
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

*expecting kEND* means you need one **class** `end`. Which is missed in your class definition.